# SELECT Count Distinct Syntax MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table: Test

```
Customer Number
5
6
7
8
8  



SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT[Customer Number])
FROM Test
```

Expected Result = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  You can use two aggregations:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct [Customer Number]
      from Test 
     ) as t;
```

Note:  This counts `NULL` values whereas `COUNT(DISTINCT)` does not.  You can filter them out in either the subquery or outer query if that is an issue.

Comment: select count(*)
from (select distinct [Customer Number]
      from prod
     ) as t WHERE RU <> '#N/A' AND [Open Amount] <> 0;    If I had to add two where clauses - This is showing as a parameter input on Access

Comment: @JohnDaly . . . You have to add them into the subquery.

Comment: Working - Thanks Gordon